# Segmentation fault executing file writing using FILE pointer

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I get a "Segmentation fault" for the following C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int, char**) {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("~/work/dog.txt", "w");
  fprintf(fp, "timer, timer3, timer5, timer6, timer7");
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: BTW, this is C code that you compile using a C++ compiler, because nobody doing C++ should be using those C APIs. They are obnoxious.

Comment: @Kuba Ober : Is there no way to keep these functions ? I cant get the new ones to work.

Comment: You can keep using them, but in C++ code it's rather awkward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your path is invalid and will never work, thus `fopen` sets `fp` to `NULL` and you get a segfault. Hint: the `~` character is expanded by the shell, you can't use it in an argument to `fopen`.

A correct, safe implementation of what you're trying to do might look as follows. This is tested. It's also the reason why sane people don't write in C unless they have no other way of doing it :)

```
// main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    const char * home = getenv("HOME");
    if (home == NULL || strlen(home) == 0 || access(home, F_OK) == -1) abort();
    const char * subPath = "/work/dog.txt";
    char * path = (char*)malloc(strlen(home) + strlen(subPath) + 1);
    if (path == NULL) abort();
    strcpy(path, home);
    strcat(path, subPath);
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "timer, timer3, timer5, timer6, timer7");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    free(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- you need to check fp for NULL before using it, else you'll get a segfault whenever the file isn't found.
- you need to resolve the full path before passing it to fopen (fopen doesn't know what to do with "~")

example:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
char path[MAX];
char *home = getenv ("HOME");
if ( home ) 
{
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/work/dog.txt", home);
    // now use path in fopen
    fp = fopen(path, "w");

    if ( fp )
    {
        fprintf(fp, "timer, timer3, timer5, timer6, timer7");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "your dog is missing" << std::endl;
    }
else
{
    std::cout << "You are homeless" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segfault happens is the file you're trying to open does not exist. This has nothing to do with Qt.

Test for the nullity of 'fp' and handle the error correctly. Something like

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/path/to/work/dog.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("File does not exist.\n");
    // throw exception or whatever.
}
```

Comment: See also Kube Ober's answer as well.